# NDK - Include a Prebuilt library and call a native function in Android Project

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

Suppose we have a certain prebuilt native library called libname.a. 
We need to call a native function contained in the native library from our Java activity. An example is this one stored in the main header file:

```
DLLEXPORT int DLLCALL function(Xhandle handle, unsigned char *srcBuf, unsigned char *dstBuf);
```

Where `Xhandle` is a struct also defined in the header file.

The files we have are structured as follows:

```
armv6
 |- header1.h
 |- header2.h
 |- ...
 |- libname.a
armv7
 |- header1.h
 |- header2.h
 |- ...
 |- libname.a
x86
 |- header1.h
 |- header2.h
 |- ...
 |- libname.a
```

We need to import this library into our Android Project. 
What we did:

- Installed the NDK and CMake tools.
- Checked include C++ support while creating the project.
- Created a jni directory in the project, and copied the files mentioned above.

Our `CMakeList.txt` file (stored in the project root folder):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( name
             STATIC # We guessed it's a static due to the .a extension
             IMPORTED # No source code (.c or .cpp) available )
```

We then created an `Android.mk` file in the jni directory:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
TARGET_ARCH_ABI := armv7

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := name
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libname.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

All of this was deduced from reading the following links:

- [Android.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html)
- [Prebuilts](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html)
- [Add Native Code](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html)

Now in our java activity, we know we need to add something like this:

```
public native int function();

// Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
static {
    System.loadLibrary("name");
}
```

We feel that we did something wrong and that we are missing something. We have to also define the arguments, and we think we should write a wrapper.

So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Run `javah` over the Java file containing your native function definition.  The will output a C header file with the correct method name.  Implement this method in a C or C++ file and in it call your pre-built function.  Don't forget to link it all together.

Comment: @RichardCritten "...Java file containing your native function definition." you mean the java activity?

Comment: The Java file with this (or similar) line in it: `public native int function();`  This line tells Java that you have a native method called `function` that takes no parameters and returns an int.  `javah` will generate the correct C function definition from the package, class and method signature.

Answer (score 0):

The **function** native method in your Java class needs

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_my_package_name_MyClass_function(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance)
```

on the C++ side. Your **libname** does not provide such exported function, therefore you must prepare it yourself, as [Richard Critten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3370124/richard-critten) explained in comments. You can put your wrapper function in file **jniWrapper.cpp**, next to **Android.mk**.

Your **Android.mk** may look like

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := name
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libname.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := jniWrapper
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jniWrapper.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := name
include $(BUILD_SHARD_LIBRARY)
```

Finally, **lodalLibrary()** cannot load static libraries; the static constructor of your Java class may look like

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("jniWrapper");
}
```